# Issue starting an activity from a different package

Tags: android

Hi I currently have two packages in my android application say `com.packagea` and `com.packageb` .Now I am attempting to activate an activity in `com.packageb` from an activity in `com.packagea` by the following code

```
    String username = ((android.widget.EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUserName)).getText().toString();
    String pass = ((android.widget.EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPass)).getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Authenticate.class);
    i.putExtra("uname", username);
    i.putExtra("pass",pass);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

However it wont even go into Authenticate.class which is in `com.packageb`. Any suggestions why it isnt going in that class. Here is how I have declared the activity in my manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Authenticate"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_options" >
    </activity>
```

Do I need to specify a package name along with this. This only happens when I attempt to call an activity from a different package. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Authenticate activity is in com.packageb and you are trying to invoke it form com.packagea package you can use the ceonvenience method [Intent.setClassName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.packageb", "com.packageb.Authenticate");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified name:

```
 com.packageb.Authenticate

    <activity
      android:name="com.packageb.Authenticate"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_options" >
  </activity>
```

instead of

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Authenticate"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_options" >
</activity>
```